# Get options from multiple select form in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to get the list of the selected options from the following form in React.

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleOptionsSelected.bind(this) }>
    <div>
        <select multiple>
            { this.getOptionList() }
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Select"/>
</form>
```

Here is my `handleOptionsSelected` implementation.

```
handleOptionsSelected(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("The selected options are " + event.target.value);
}
```

However, I got `undefined` value for `event.target.value`.

Does someone know how to correct the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ref in your `<select ref={node => this.select = node}  multiple>` and loop over the values.

Something like this.

```js
class Example extends React.Component{
  handleOptionsSelected(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const selected = [];
    for(let option of this.select.options){
      if(option.selected){
       selected.push(option.value)
      }
    }
    console.log(selected);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
     <form onSubmit={ this.handleOptionsSelected.bind(this) }>
        <div>
            <select ref={node => this.select = node} multiple="true">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Select"/>
    </form>
    )
  }

}
  

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems the `<form>` is not necessary here.